# Hive Java UDTF Error: ArrayIndexOutofBounds:1

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

When I run my java function on Hive I constantly get ArrayOutOfBounds Error.

This is the Java code I am using that I have packaged into a Jar file to use with Hive:
Under this please find the hive code to implement the above Java Code.

```
public class similarity_report extends GenericUDTF 
{
private PrimitiveObjectInspector stringOI = null;
@Override
public StructObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] args) throws UDFArgumentException
{
//if (args.length != 1) 
//
{ // throw new UDFArgumentException("similarityReport() takes exactly one argument"); // }
if (args[0].getCategory() != ObjectInspector.Category.PRIMITIVE
&& ((PrimitiveObjectInspector) args[0]).getPrimitiveCategory() != PrimitiveObjectInspector.PrimitiveCategory.STRING)
{ throw new UDFArgumentException("similarityReport() takes a string as a parameter"); }
stringOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) args[0];
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>(41);
List<ObjectInspector> fieldOIs = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>(41);
fieldNames.add("NAME_x");
fieldNames.add("VOTER ID_x");
fieldNames.add("FATHERS' NAME_x");
fieldNames.add("PIN CODE_x");
fieldNames.add("AREA_x");
fieldNames.add("TEHSIL_x");
fieldNames.add("DISTRICT_x");
fieldNames.add("POLICE STATION_x");
fieldNames.add("AGE_x");
fieldNames.add("Y-O-B_x");
fieldNames.add("GENDER_x");
fieldNames.add("HOUSE NUMBER_x");
fieldNames.add("STREET ADDRESS_x");
fieldNames.add("UNIQUE ID_x");
fieldNames.add("EDIT MAX_x");
fieldNames.add("MATCH ID_x");
fieldNames.add("FAKE MAX_x");
fieldNames.add("NAME_y");
fieldNames.add("VOTER ID_y");
fieldNames.add("FATHERS' NAME_y");
fieldNames.add("PIN CODE_y");
fieldNames.add("AREA_y");
fieldNames.add("TEHSIL_y");
fieldNames.add("DISTRICT_y");
fieldNames.add("POLICE STATION_y");
fieldNames.add("AGE_y");
fieldNames.add("Y-O-B_y");
fieldNames.add("GENDER_y");
fieldNames.add("HOUSE NUMBER_y");
fieldNames.add("STREET ADDRESS_y");
fieldNames.add("UNIQUE ID_y");
fieldNames.add("EDIT MAX_y");
fieldNames.add("MATCH ID_y");
fieldNames.add("FAKE MAX_y");
fieldNames.add("NAME SCORE");
fieldNames.add("ADDRESS SCORE");
fieldNames.add("CITY MATCH");
fieldNames.add("ZIP MATCH");
fieldNames.add("RELATIVE NAME SCORE");
fieldNames.add("VOTER ID MATCH");
fieldNames.add("KEY");

fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
```

.
   .
   .

```
fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector);
return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldOIs);
}
public ArrayList<Object[]> processInputRecord(String row)
{
ArrayList<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
//ensure none of the fields are empty
String[] tokens = row.split("\t");

System.out.println(tokens.length);
```

As per the suggestion I added the above line^^

```
String Name_x = tokens[0];
String VoterID_x = tokens[1];
String FathersName_x = tokens[2];
String PinCode_x = tokens[3];
String Area_x = tokens[4];
String Tehsil_x = tokens[5];
String District_x = tokens[6];
String PoliceStation_x = tokens[7];
String Age_x = tokens[8];
String YOB_x = tokens[9];
String Gender_x = tokens[10];
String HouseNumber_x = tokens[11];
String StreetAddress_x = tokens[12];
String UniqueID_x = tokens[1];
String EditMax_x = tokens[14];
String MatchID_x = tokens[15];
String FakeMax_x = tokens[16];
String Name_y = tokens[17];
String VoterID_y = tokens[18];
String FathersName_y = tokens[19];
String PinCode_y = tokens[20];
String Area_y = tokens[21];
String Tehsil_y = tokens[22];
String District_y = tokens[23];
String PoliceStation_y = tokens[24];
String Age_y = tokens[25];
String YOB_y = tokens[26];
String Gender_y = tokens[27];
String HouseNumber_y = tokens[28];
String StreetAddress_y = tokens[29];
String UniqueID_y = tokens[18];
String EditMax_y = tokens[31];
String MatchID_y = tokens[32];
String FakeMax_y = tokens[33];
String NameScore = tokens[34];
String AddressScore = tokens[35];
String CityMatch = tokens[36];
String ZipMatch = tokens[37];
String RelativeNameScore = tokens[38];
String VoterIDMatch = tokens[39];
String Key = tokens[40];
String Address_x;
String Address_y;
String matchType = "";

if (matchType == "similar")
{
result.add(new Object[]
{ Name_x, VoterID_x, FathersName_x, PinCode_x, Area_x, Tehsil_x, District_x, PoliceStation_x, Age_x, YOB_x, Gender_x, HouseNumber_x, StreetAddress_x, UniqueID_x, EditMax_x, MatchID_x, FakeMax_x, NameScore, AddressScore, CityMatch, ZipMatch, RelativeNameScore, VoterIDMatch, Key});
result.add(new Object[] { Name_y, VoterID_y, FathersName_y, PinCode_y, Area_y, Tehsil_y, District_y, PoliceStation_y, Age_y, YOB_y, Gender_y, HouseNumber_y, StreetAddress_y, UniqueID_y, EditMax_y, MatchID_y, FakeMax_y, NameScore, AddressScore, CityMatch, ZipMatch, RelativeNameScore, VoterIDMatch, Key});

}

else if (matchType == "identical")
{

result.add(new Object[] { Name_x, VoterID_x, FathersName_x, PinCode_x, Area_x, Tehsil_x, District_x, PoliceStation_x, Age_x, YOB_x, Gender_x, HouseNumber_x, StreetAddress_x, UniqueID_x, EditMax_x, MatchID_x, FakeMax_x, NameScore, AddressScore, CityMatch, ZipMatch, RelativeNameScore, VoterIDMatch, Key}
);
}
else if (matchType == "different")
{
result.add(new Object[]
{ Name_x, VoterID_x, FathersName_x, PinCode_x, Area_x, Tehsil_x, District_x, PoliceStation_x, Age_x, YOB_x, Gender_x, HouseNumber_x, StreetAddress_x, UniqueID_x, EditMax_x, MatchID_x, FakeMax_x, NameScore, AddressScore, CityMatch, ZipMatch, RelativeNameScore, VoterIDMatch, Key}
);
result.add(new Object[]
{ Name_y, VoterID_y, FathersName_y, PinCode_y, Area_y, Tehsil_y, District_y, PoliceStation_y, Age_y, YOB_y, Gender_y, HouseNumber_y, StreetAddress_y, UniqueID_y, EditMax_y, MatchID_y, FakeMax_y, NameScore, AddressScore, CityMatch, ZipMatch, RelativeNameScore, VoterIDMatch, Key}
);
}
return result;
}
@Override
public void process(Object[] record) throws HiveException 
{
final String row = stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(record[0]).toString();
ArrayList<Object[]> results = processInputRecord(row);
Iterator<Object[]> it = results.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{ Object[] r = it.next(); forward(r); }
}
@Override
public void close() throws HiveException
{ // do nothing }
}
```

This is the Hive Code to Process above code on a hive table:

```
set mapred.job.queue.name=buanlst;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS saihieldb;
USE saihieldb;
CREATE TABLE datafile_to_dedupe (name_x String, voterid_x String, fathersname_x String, pincode_x String, area_x String, tehsil_x String, district_x String, policestation_x String, age_x String, yob_x String, gender_x String, housenumber_x String, streetaddress_x String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/idn/home/sbaks31/APRIORI_MUMBAI_SAMPLE_TAB_DELIMITED.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE datafile_to_dedupe;
ALTER TABLE datafile_to_dedupe ADD COLUMNS (uniqueid_x String, editmax_x String, matchid_x String, fakemax_x String);
CREATE TABLE datafile_to_dedupe1 (name_y String, voterid_y String, fathersname_y String, pincode_y String, area_y String, tehsil_y String, district_y String, policestation_y String, age_y String, yob_y String, gender_y String, housenumber_y String, streetaddress_y String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/idn/home/sbaks31/APRIORI_MUMBAI_SAMPLE_TAB_DELIMITED.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE datafile_to_dedupe1;
ALTER TABLE datafile_to_dedupe ADD COLUMNS (uniqueid_y String, editmax_y String, matchid_y String, fakemax_y String);
CREATE TABLE crossed (name_x String, voterid_x String, fathersname_x String, pincode_x String, area_x String, tehsil_x String, district_x String, policestation_x String, age_x String, yob_x String, gender_x String, housenumber_x String, streetaddress_x String, uniqueid_x String, editmax_x String, matchid_x String, fakemax_x String, name_y String, voterid_y String, fathersname_y String, pincode_y String, area_y String, tehsil_y String, district_y String, policestation_y String, age_y String, yob_y String, gender_y String, housenumber_y String, streetaddress_y String, uniqueid_y String, editmax_y String, matchid_y String, fakemax_y String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE crossed SELECT * FROM saihieldb.datafile_to_dedupe CROSS JOIN saihieldb.datafile_to_dedupe1 on (datafile_to_dedupe.name_x = datafile_to_dedupe1.name_y);
ALTER TABLE crossed ADD COLUMNS (namescore String, addressscore String, citymatch String, zipmatch String, relativenamescore String, voteridmatch String, Key String);
add jar /idn/home/sbaks31/DedupeFinal1.jar.filepart;
create temporary function fun3 as 'com.similarity_report';
CREATE VIEW newview4 AS select fun3(name_x, voterid_x, fathersname_x, pincode_x, area_x, tehsil_x, district_x, policestation_x, age_x, yob_x, gender_x, housenumber_x, streetaddress_x, uniqueid_x, editmax_x, matchid_x, fakemax_x, name_y, voterid_y, fathersname_y, pincode_y, area_y, tehsil_y, district_y, policestation_y, age_y, yob_y, gender_y, housenumber_y, streetaddress_y, uniqueid_y, editmax_y, matchid_y, fakemax_y, namescore, addressscore, citymatch, zipmatch, relativenamescore, voteridmatch, Key) from saihieldb.crossed;
select * from newview4 limit 10;
```

^^This is where i recieve the error. please let me know what is going wrong??

After I try to print the length of the tokens array I get that the length is only 1.. Could someone please clarify why it is only taking 1 value in the array??

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a few lines of code to where you think the problem might lie? cause this is just way too much code. Please read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @philantrovert I narrowed the code down further, but due to the new error which is my Tokens Array only has a length of one, I am not sure where the problem might lie..

Comment: Probably because the string that you're trying to split here is not tab-delimited.

Comment: @philantrovert However isnt this string received from the Hive Table? And the hive table is formatted as tab-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

After this line of code:

> String[] tokens = row.split("\t");

Write:

> System.out.println(tokens.length);

And put a break point at that line in order to debug.
This will allow you to see what length your array actually is.
Because if your array "tokens" is of length 5, you'll get an exception when you try to call tokens[6], tokens[7], <...>, tokens[40] etc.

Comment: After adding the line you suggested it prints 1, as in the length of the array is only 1.. Why do you think this is the case? Thanks!